# View keeps generating multiple unwanted rows

Tags: mysql, database, view, xampp

my view that i created generates unnecessary rows, it basically multiplies my rows to 1000.
How do i stop this from happening?
this is what i use to create my  view:

```
CREATE VIEW vworders_reportjb AS
SELECT orders.orderid, 
customers.cust_name,
customers.address,
items.itemname,
orders.orderdate
FROM orders, customers, items;
```

Comment: You do not specify the relation between tables rows (joining conditions).

Comment: 'INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html